# Flask/Keras webservice ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.keras'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, flask, keras, importerror

i'm building a simple webservice to classify an image.
Separated my keras model classifies correctly and the flask service is running.

But when i try to use the keras model in my flask app ...

```
from flask import Flask

from myproject.keras_model_wrapper import get_result

APP = Flask(__name__)


@APP.route('/')
def keras_result():
    return get_result()

if __name__ == 'main':
    APP.run()
```

... an import error occurs.

```
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<python_path>\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "<python_path>\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 966, in main
    cli.main(prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 860, in run_command
    extra_files=extra_files,
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1008, in run_simple
    run_with_reloader(inner, extra_files, reloader_interval, reloader_type)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 337, in run_with_reloader
    reloader.run()
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 202, in run
    for filename in chain(_iter_module_files(), self.extra_files):
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 24, in _iter_module_files
    filename = getattr(module, "__file__", None)
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "<project_path>\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "<python_path>\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.keras'
```

I don't know if it's important that the import system searches out of my .venv 
and TBH I have no idea, what exactly I should search for solving it on my own.

Every hint is welcome

Comment: I haven't solved the issue completely but I have figured out that it has something to do with flask debug mode being set to true. So as a painfully annoying work around you could turn off flask debug.

Comment: @xanderer Yes, setting debug to False makes it running. Thanks a lot. I would accept and rate it as an answer

Comment: @brnc_ I added it as an answer with information about the issue in GitHub.

Comment: FWIW, over on GitHub, people report this issue with Django and Falcon too. So while it seems related to Flask based on this question, possibly it is not.  I have this problem (am using Flask too), although it is not easily reproduced-- sometimes the app starts and runs my keras model.

Comment: @xanderer bnrc_ Hi, After switching off Falsk debug did u succeed to run not only the flask application, but also tensorflow model itself?

Comment: @MarcelMars everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't consider this to be a solution but Setting `flask_debug=1`(off) will allow you to continue working but you will need to restart the server after every change.

The issue is being tracked in TensorFlow Repo at the link below.

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.keras' in Flask](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34607)

Comment: the problem with debug off is that your app stops live reloading after changes

Comment: That IS a pain, but restarting is better than don't having a running server at all

Comment: @xanderer you saved me!

Answer (score -1):

A Workaround that Works perfectly for Flask==1.1.1 and tensorflow==2.1.0

In Flask you should put "`import tensorflow as tf`" in the "`__init__.py`" file.

In Django you should put "`import tensorflow as tf`" in the "`manage.py`" file.